# Get the type of redux's state

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, types, react-redux

I want to get a type for redux state, which will be used to mock said state.

So far I figured out I have this Reducer:

```
(alias) const reducer: {
    selectedElement: Reducer<StructureElement, AnyAction>;
    fetchedState: Reducer<FetchedState, AnyAction>;
    ... 10 more ...;
    mesApi: Reducer<...>;
}
```

So what I want to do, is somehow get the `StructureElement`, `FetchedState` and so on from inside of the `Reducer</here/, AnyAction>;` part.

How can I achieve that?

Or is there a better way to get combined state type? It has to be done automatically though. I don't want to change types in 2 places when it should be auto-generated.

If I try this:

```
type State = typeof reducer;
```

I get

> Type '{ selectedElement: Reducer<StructureElement, AnyAction>; fetchedState: Reducer<FetchedState, AnyAction>; ... 10 more ...; mesApi: Reducer<...>; }' is not assignable to type '{ selectedElement?: { stateId: string; parentId: string; hasChild: boolean; pathList: string[]; name: string; color: string; isActive: boolean; level: number; children?: ...[]; key?: string; type: StateType; }; ... 11 more ...; mesApi?: { ...; }; }'.
> Types of property 'selectedElement' are incompatible.

which makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was being stupid. I had something like this back from the basic setup:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

And it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to simply model it explicitly and then import those types where you need them:

```
export type UserState = {
    readonly isLoggedIn: boolean;
    // other user state here
};

// Type for entire global redux state
export type AppState = {
    users: UserState;
    // other sub-states here
};
```

Comment: This is a good practice because one of the things the Typescript compiler should do is check that the reducers output state with the right data type for all cases. If the state is inferred, that might not happen.

Answer (score 1):

I personally create a slice for each feature that I want in my state, then I have a file in which I'll first declare and export my RootState Type, and then I'll combine all of my reducers.

```js
export interface RootState {
  pokemon: pokemonState;
  pokemonTrainer: pokemonTrainerState;
}

const reducer = combineReducers<RootState>({
  pokemon: pokemonSLice,
  pokemonTrainer: pokemonTrainerSlice,
});
```

Where `pokemonState` and `pokemonTrainerState` are the types of each feature.

And then I'll use `RootState` wherever I need.